# Dual touchscreen monitor issues

Tags: windows-7, display

I have two HP Compaq L2105TM dual-touch monitors that are connected to a Matrox DualHead2Go system and then connected to my laptops docking station. The USBs from each that are responsible for the touch signals however are connected directly to the docking station.In Windows 7 I have set the monitors up to display through the VGA connection (Matrox system) and it is working correctly except when it comes to the touch functionality.

When I touch the screen the calibration seems to be a good 4 to 5 inches off where I am actually touching and usually on the opposite monitor. Please help, as I would like to use this setup in testing my touchscreen apps.

Thanks,

Patrick

Answer (score 1):

Bear with me, I use a similar setup at work through a Matrox THTG but with a different make of monitor. I'll check how I have those set up on Monday and get back to you if no-one else has before then.

I'm sure the setup utilities will have similar functionality

OK, the NEC utility is very simplistic and uses the following steps:

1. Assign a name to each touchscreen USB input
2. Allocate the named input to a monitor (Left/Right)
3. Run the touchscreen calibration for each input
   The calibration utility for NEC has a drop-down box so you can select each touchscreen input in turn.
   If you still can't get it to work, you could try posing a question to HP support in case there is a known problem/updated driver.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm attempting your solution now.

Comment: @Tog: commands please, if you used `xinput` , 2012 i am looking for similar.

Comment: @YumYumYum - Please post a new question. This one refers specifically to Windows 7 using the manufacturer's utility.